# On board Video Card vs PCIE 2.0 Video Card Priority..?

Tags: video, graphics, priority

I'm making a build and have selected both a video card and Motherboard that I like and should be compatible.  However, the motherboard has an ATI on board video card and the video card I selected is an Nvidia stand alone card to be plugged into PCIE 2.0.  Will the Nvidia stand alone card take priority over/bypass the ATI card?  Is there a compatibility issue here?  Here are the two parts...

Motherboard: ASUS M5A88-V EVO AM3+ AMD 880G HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX AMD Motherboard

Video Card: EVGA SuperClocked 012-P3-1572-AR GeForce GTX 570 (Fermi) 1280MB 320-bit GDDR5 PCI Express 2.0 x16 HDCP Ready SLI Support Video Card

Answer (score 0):

This depends on where you plug your screen in. Because you add a graphics card, you will use the graphics card's output, and thus the graphics card. If you would plug it into the on-board card's output, you would use that on-board card. There are also some boards or add-in boards that offer HydraLogix. This allows the use of completely different cards together - even ATI and Nvidia - in some sort of SLI/CrossFire mode.

Answer (score 0):

For most motherboards with an on-board video chipset, it's an either/or situation that you have to set up in the BIOS settings.  Either you can use the on-board video, or you can install your own video card.  It's relatively rare to have a motherboard that lets you use both the on-board graphics and an add-in graphics card.  You will need to consult the motherboard documentation or their website knowledge base.

Sometimes it will automatically detect an installed card and sometimes it won't, depending on the board.  If, when you first boot, nothing appears on the monitor, try plugging your video into the on-board graphics output and rebooting.  Often times the default setting is to have the on-board chipset be the active set.  At that point you can go into the bios and disable the on-board graphics.

Comment: but it won't ignore the stand alone card completely right?  All i might have to do is set it as the active card in the BIOS

Comment: No, it won't ignore the add-in card.  The only question is whether or not it automatically detects and uses the add-in card or if you have to manually disable the on-board graphics in the BIOS.